# AWS managed Active Directory user Authentication issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-directory-services

My task is to connect AWS managed Active Directory from my application server

These are the steps that I followed:

1. Create an Active Directory in the us-east-1 region using AWS console
2. Launch Windows EC2 instance and connect Active Directory to that Windows instance
3. Now I install the administrative tools to manage users and computers and created one user in this Active Directory
4. I am trying to connect AWS Managed Microsoft AD to my node.js application but I get an error

   ```
    > ERROR: {"errno":-4039,
    > "code":"ETIMEDOUT",
    > "syscall":"connect", 
    > "address":"72.13.4.97","port":389}
   ```

Did I miss any steps to configure the Windows instance? Or do I need to add any rules in security group?

Please help me out

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear on which instance is the node.js app, and whether it is domain joined, but the ``` "address":"72.13.4.97","port":389}``` is not looking good. You are not supposed to be connecting to the AD on a public IP. Not to mention that the IP you are trying to hit doesn't seem to be from AWS IP ranges to begin with (or not in the publicly shared list of AWS IPs to be precise).

Comment: ISSUE:
we are trying to authenticate users using node js application
Below is the nodejs code:
var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');
var config = {
url: 'ldap://win-84n9tmba6af.develop.com:389',
baseDN: 'dc=develop,dc=com'
};
var ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);
var username = 'vamsi1';
var password = 'Vamsi@123';
// Authenticate
ad.authenticate(username, password, function(err, auth) {
if (err) {
console.log('ERROR: '+JSON.stringify(err));
return;
}
if (auth) {
console.log('Authenticated!');
}
else {
console.log('Authentication failed!');
}
});

Comment: Below is the issue we are facing :
ERROR: {"errno":-4039,"code":"ETIMEDOUT","syscall":"connect","address":"72.13.4.97","port":38}
and when we run the same code on AD server it is working.
Did I miss any configuration

Comment: Please edit your question add the information from those comments to it in a structured way. It's still not clear where the nodejs is supposed to be running (instance in AWS, on-prem, etc?)